# How to name SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint on CREATE two tables columns into a relationship TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, tablecolumn

i was just wondering if there is a way to name a foreign key on create table

```
FOREIGN KEY (uuid) REFERENCES employee(uuid));
```

i tried to do this and name my foreign key as fk1 but i've got syntax errors

```
FOREIGN KEY fk1 (uuid) REFERENCES employee(uuid));
```

error

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is com.jda.cloudsql.common.MigrationException: org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException:

  FOREIGN KEY FK1[*] (UUID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(UUID)) "; expected "("; SQL statement:
```

Comment: Are you trying to _add_ a foreign key to a table which already exists, or are you asking how to do this from a `CREATE TABLE` statement.  You may certainly name a foreign key when adding it during create table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen from a CREATE TABLE, i actually dropped my previous table and recreate it

Comment: [See here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/) for how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT `customized_foreign_key_name` FOREIGN KEY (`uuid`) REFERENCES `employee` (`uuid`)
```

Comment: i am doing a create table, not an alter. I dont know if that will work in this case. it expects a type instead of a constraint?

Comment: Why don't you create the table first and then start creating foreign keys?

Comment: yeah that is exactly what i am about to do . thank you

Comment: Glad I could hep.